# display data in div based on item clicked

Tags: php, jquery

Based on the question asked here: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-display-a-div-table-when-a-link-is-clicked

I used the code given by the top answer.

Now, my code is modified to use variables:

```
    echo '<a href="#" onclick="toggleAppearance();">'.$row['Name'] .'</a>';
```

It's in a while loop.

```
    <div id="data-table" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <table>
    <?php
    if $Name == 
    ?>
    </table>
    </div>
```

My div is supposed to show the data for the item whose Name is selected.  eg: if "Robin" is selected, Robin's data will be shown.  so how do I get the div to check which Name/link was clicked and then show the data for that Name/link?

Comment: incomplete `if $Name ==` - *"It's in a while loop"*  what `while` loop?

Comment: @Fred-ii- - please **assume** it's in a while loop because **that's what I put down**.  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
        echo '<a href="#" onclick="toggleAppearance();">'.$row['Name'] .'</a>'; } The code is incomplete because I have no idea how to complete it, hence the question.

Comment: You could add the name as a param to your `toggleAppearance()` function -> `onclick="toggleAppearance(\''.$row['Name'] .'\');"`, and have that value also in your table, ie. `<div id="data-table'.$row['Name'] .'"...` or `<div data-name="'.$row['Name'] .'"...`. So when that name is clicked the synced table/div is shown

Comment: This is the jquery script:  `<script>
 function toggleAppearance()
{
     var dataDiv = document.getElementById("data-table");
     if(dataDiv.style.visibility == "hidden")
     {
          dataDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
     }
     else
     {
          dataDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
     }
}
</script> ` so how would I edit the `<div>` that displays the data to display the data based on what Name was clicked on?  If I put `id="data-table'.$row['Name'] .'"`, would that fill the div with the data for that corresponding Name?

Comment: By the way, I put your code in but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little hard to follow. Hopefully this can clear up some of your front-end issues.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
<h3>Triggers</h3>
<p class='table-reference' data-record-ref='1'>Highlight Row #1</p>
<p class='table-reference' data-record-ref='2'>Highlight Row #2</p>
<p class='table-reference' data-record-ref='3'>Highlight Row #3</p>
<hr>
<h3>Table</h3>
<table id="record-table">
<thead>
  <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Data</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr data-record='1'>
     <td>#1</td>
     <td>Record</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-record='2'>
     <td>#2</td>
     <td>Record</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-record='3'>
     <td>#3</td>
     <td>Record</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
     $("*[data-record-ref]").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).data("record-ref");
        var element = $("*[data-record='"+id+"']");

        if(!!element) {
           $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
           element.toggleClass("highlight");
        } else {
           console.error("Record Not Find.");
        }        
     });
  });
}) ($);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t0nj2nfe/7/)

Comment: the link is supposed to hold a variable.  it's not static.  i have a while loop that echoes out the a hrefs.  if I have 5 items in the database, 5 links will appear.  each link holds a variable.  so when a link is clicked on, the data that matches with that variable will display in a div.  so if a link's variable value is "Bob", then all data corresponding to "Bob" in the database should display in the div.